# Selenium Unable to locate element ng dropdown panel

Tags: python, selenium, drop-down-menu, element, locate

I am new to selenium webdriver with python.This is my first script

I am trying to select value "300-500" from dropdown but getting error "elenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@class="ng-dropdown-panel ng-select-bottom"]//div[3]"}"

I first clicked on dropdown so it will show list "

```
browser.find_element(By.NAME, "organization").click()
```

Then i write this to click on value "

```
time.sleep(1)
browser.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@class="ng-dropdown-panel ng-select-bottom"]//div[3]').click()
```

"
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ar3Ny.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1vxCE.png)

Comment: Can you add the `HTML souruce` for the element?

Comment: Can you share the website that you want to scrape?

Comment: @Akzy i added image for it

Comment: @skyriver For the security concern i can not share site

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below *solution*.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by
import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui
import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support
import expected_conditions as EC

element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
   EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(text(),'10-50']")))  #if you want to choose 10-50

element.click();
```

***OR***

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
       EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[normalize-space()='10-5=0']")))  #if you want to choose 10-50
    
    element.click();
```